# How to protect data of list item

Tags: ssom

As you know that Users with edit permission on List can edit List Item via CSOM or Rest API. It does not matter if the data is simple, but in case the data of list item is essential and stored with a format, it will absolutely not secure at all.

It can be done by setting Read permission for this list and use Administrator Privilege when performing create and update list item. However, if doing so, we will have to rely on SOM that I do not like much.

I also think about Audit log for list Item level, but I am not sure about whether or not we can recover list item in case data is edited deliberately.

I would like to know your idea or experience in such situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can have versioning and content approval on the items of the list. Versioning allow you to retail previous versions of the item. Content approval allows you to review any new item/ updated item before its made live.

To enable this feature -

1. Go to List Settings
2. Click on Versioning settings
3. `Require content approval for submitted items? - Yes`
   `Create a version each time you edit an item in this list? - Yes`
4. You may want to set the no of versions you want to retainif you like
5. Click on OK.

There is a [article here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-site-list-or-library-to-require-approval-of-items-or-files-7f765a32-741d-4314-b27f-9b785437518c) around this